# how to localize DateLabel and NumberLabel customFormat attribute?

Tags: gwt, localization, uibinder

I am in the process of localizing a rather large GWT UIbinder code base and ran across a couple of instances where the process of setting attributes does not work.

[DateLabel javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DateLabel.html)

[NumberLabel javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/NumberLabel.html)

I need to specify the date format and number format in a LocalizableResource_xx.properties file for  DateLabel and NumberLabel widgets.

I tried converting this fragment

```
   <g:DateLabel styleName="{style.formPromptData}" 
        ui:field="createDate" customFormat="MMM d, yyyy" />
```

using [the ui:attribute method](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinderI18n#HTML_attributes_that_need_translation) with no success

Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
    [ERROR] No method found to apply message attribute customFormat Element  (:63)

Is there a way to localize these elements?

Comment: Why do you need to localize them? They are already locale-specific, as long as you use PredefinedFormat.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin And the question is about `customFormat`, not predefined formats.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Exactly. So why try to localize customFormat, when they can use PredefinedFormat, which is already localized.

Comment: Answer: when you cannot find a `PredefinedFormat` that fits you needs. Otherwise, why would there be a `customFormat` to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`customFormat="XXX"` translates to `DateTimeFormat.getFormat("XXX")` and is no different wrt localization: that is, it's not localizable.

If you want a localizable custom format, use a [`CustomDateTimeFormat`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/shared/CustomDateTimeFormat.html) (that currently relies on ICU4J's [`DateTimePatternGenerator`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DateTimePatternGenerator.html)) or a [`Constants`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Constants.html) or [`Messages`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Messages.html) interface. Instantiate it with `<ui:with>` and use with `customFormat="{intf.customPattern}"` (`format="{intf.customPattern}"` actually if you use a `CustomDateTimeFormat`).